# How to copy specific rows and columns from a spreadsheet to notepad?

Tags: excel, xml, vba, visual-studio

Im setting up a macro which allows me to copy 2 columns from a spreadsheet into a new text file. This is a columns E and F. I've only been able to copy and entire spreadsheet to note pad, I think I need help with the ranges but I have included what I have so far.

I have included the code in which I have currently tested which allows me to copy the entire excel spreadsheet but I only want columns E & F to be copied to the notepad.

```
Sub exceltoText()

Dim FileName, sLine, Deliminator As String
Dim LastCol, LastRow, FileNumber As Integer

FileName = "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\New\Test.txt"
Deliminator = "|"

LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
FileNumber = FreeFile

Open FileName For Output As FileNumber
 For i = 1 To LastRow
 For J = 1 To LastCol
 If J = LastCol Then
 sLine = sLine & Cells(i, J).Value
Else
 sLine = sLine & Cells(i, J).Value & Deliminator
End If
Next J

Print #FileNumber, sLine
 sLine = ""
Next i
Close #FileNumber

MsgBox "Text File complete."

End Sub
```

Column E & F are copied into a new notepad file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you have to change the part involving the column, reading data only from `E` and `F` columns.
Some suggestion to improve **code quality**:

- Use always `Option Explicit`. It may save you hours of debugging in some cases.
- You have to declare your variables specifying the type for each one, otherwyse VBA will assigns the default `Variant` if not.
- Indent the code using <kbd>tab</kbd>, it will improve a lot the readability.

Here's the code with the solution and above suggestions applied:

```
Option Explicit

Sub exceltoText()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim FileName As String, sLine As String, Deliminator As String
    Dim LastRow As Integer, FileNumber As Integer

    FileName = "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\New\Test.txt"
    Deliminator = "|"

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    FileNumber = FreeFile

    Open FileName For Output As FileNumber
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 1 To 2
            If j = 1 Then
                sLine = sLine & Cells(i, 5).Value
            Else
                sLine = sLine & Cells(i, 6).Value & Deliminator
            End If
        Next j

        Print #FileNumber, sLine
        sLine = ""
    Next i
    Close #FileNumber

    MsgBox "Text File complete."
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: fully qualify range references and avoid using activesheet in favour of using sheet name where possible.